# Getting an operator symbol out of a string

Tags: java, eclipse, string, math, operators

If I have the equation `7 + 13 = 20` as a string, how would I go about getting the operator symbol + out of the equation?

```
String operator = fileContent.substring(fileContent.indexOf('+'));
```

I tried something along these lines, as well as changing several things in it, but I have not been able to get the operator out. I've only been able to get it to return things like `+ 13 = 20` or `13 = 20` but never the operator alone.

I cannot use regex, try/catch, arrays, or SystemTokenizer for this.

Also, there will not always be spaces between the numbers, and they will not always be just one or two digits in size.

One last thing. I also need it so that if the operator were to be put into something like `problem = (firstNumber + operator + secondNumber)` it would actually work to compute the math.

The expected output, or at least what I'm trying to do, is to have it take the first and second number, and read the operator so that it can do the math of the problem. Its really confusing and I'm sorry.

```
int first = Integer.parseInt(fileContent.substring(0, fileContent.indexOf(" ")));
int second = secondNumber(result, fileContent);
int last = Integer.parseInt(result.substring(result.indexOf("=") + 1));
```

Here's the code I have to get the first, second, and the answer numbers, but I need to get the operator symbol out in a way that I can put it between the first and second numbers so that it will actually do the math, and so I can check it against the answer number.

Its for an assignment that will act as a "math problem grader" but none of the operators are the same.

I need it to take `7 and 13` and print `20` as the answer.

Comment: What kind of stupid requirement is this? Use two substrings. One for before the `+` and one for after `+`. Concatenate those strings.

Comment: Why can't you use regex, try/catch, arrays or SystemTokenizer? Whatever your instructor taught you in the last couple of lectures is probably what you should be using. Also, you should really post code indicating what you've tried.

Comment: Please show what the expected output is.

Comment: Are you trying to output `+` or `7 13 = 20`?

Comment: I'm still confused as to what you want. "I need it to take 7 and 13 and print 20 as the answer," what does that mean? Is the String going to be = "7 13" and you want it to output "20"?

Comment: I need it to read 7 and 13 and then read what the operator is and print out the answer like a regular math problem. Like 7 + 13 and print 20, or 2 * 3 and print 6

Comment: @CherryBomb95 check my answer (the edit) and give me some feedback on it .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer will give the output `+`. Considering your variable name is `operator`, I assume that's what you want.

Using `substring`:

```
String operator = fileContent.substring(fileContent.indexOf('+'), fileContent.indexOf('+') + 1);
```

or written more readably:

```
int index = fileContent.indexOf('+');
String operator = fileContent.substring(index, index + 1);
```

---

Using `charAt`:

```
char operator = fileContent.charAt(fileContent.indexOf('+'));
```

or written more readably:

```
int index = fileContent.indexOf('+');
char operator = fileContent.charAt(index);
```

---

**Edit**:

Here is how to find the first and second numbers:

```
String eqn = "7 + 13 = 20";

int operatorIndex = eqn.indexOf(operator); // already defined operator as a String
int equalIndex = eqn.indexOf('=');

int first = Integer.parseInt(eqn.substring(0, operatorIndex).trim());
int second = Integer.parseInt(eqn.substring(operatorIndex + 1, equalIndex).trim());
```

Now we have `String operator = "+";` and `int first = 7;` and `int second = 13;`

[Click this sentence if you don't know what a switch statement is in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html). It's just a different way of using an if-structure. It's not difficult to understand. I can rewrite is using an if-structure if you need me too, though.

I would just use this:

```
String operator = "+";

int first = 7; int second = 13;

switch (operator)
{
    case "+": 
        System.out.print("" + (first + second));
        break;

    case "-": 
        System.out.print("" + (first - second));
        break;

    case "*": 
        System.out.print("" + (first * second));
        break;

    case "/": 
        System.out.print("" + (first / second));
        break;

    default: System.out.print("not sum, difference, product or quotient");
}
```

In that case where `operator = "+";`, the output is `20`. If `operator = "-";`, the output is `-6`.

Comment: While I understand what you're doing, it doesn't actually work with what I already have, but it has given me an idea on what I need to do for this problem.

Comment: @CherryBomb95 check the new update again. and keep me posted on how I can change my code to give you your desired output.

Comment: It works, but there are errors because I'm taking my data from a file. Other than that, it works perfectly.

Comment: For different operators you will need to either check `contains` on each operator or make a line of `indexOf` and check if `operatorIndex > -1` before you make a substring with the index. `String#contains` simply returns `indexOf(str) > -1` so checking the return value of indexOf is preferred since contains would be redundant.

Comment: @Radiodef Yup. I just didn't know what he was asking at first and didn't feel like doing it afterward. He can do that himself; my algorithm answers his question. Thanks

Comment: Hi, I was also wondering if you could show me how this would be done with if statements? and I'm also having difficulty getting a method to return the char. Thanks

Comment: @CherryBomb95 This is a link to a pastie I wrote with how to do it with a if-statements: http://pastie.org/private/xqrvhxcosvvrjaepqnl97q . As for the method not correctly returning a char, you're going to have to be a lot more specific.

Answer (score 2):

Remove everything else:

```
String operator = fileContent.replaceAll("[^-+*/]", "");;
```

Note that the minus sign must come first or last in the character class or be escaped, otherwise it's a range operator.

Comment: Of course, the sensible answer is not allowed. Smells like homework.